# Touchscreen as a drawing canvas for photoshop

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, adobe-photoshop

I am willing to buy a captive touchscreen monitor to use it as a drawing canvas.

I have chosen this monitor from dell:
http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-s2240t/pd

It support 10 point touch and its HD.
I called customer support of dell about using Touch Screen pen, and they said it will work with the screen.

But my main question is that, is this a better idea to use this touch screen as drawing canvas ?

I use touchpad tablet, and I dont like it much cause I have to see desktop while drawing.

So did anybody tried this ? specially for photoshop ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fingers get in the way of what you're drawing so I feel you. See if you can use a stylus with the touch screen. This feels a lot more natural. Also, depending on the touch screen manufacturer, some have driver function that lets you shift the "hot spot" away in relation to where you're touching so you can see where you're drawing.